# XSL template, show table column if at least one value in node has an entry

Tags: if-statement, variables, xslt, parameters

I haven XSL template, and depending on the content of the data, I call a different template to draw my table.

What I would like to achieve is that before calling the template, I check all child nodes to see if there is a value for a specific node. If there is, then I would like to draw an additional column in my table to display this. If there is not, then I do not want to draw this column.

My XML is structured such that:

```
    <group>    
        <item>
            <name>NAME1</name>
            <element>
                <type>model</type>
            </element>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>name2</name>
            <element />
        </item>
    </group>
```

when there is no 'type',  element node is condensed to `<element />`.  What I am trying to achieve is for each item in my group, check if any of them have data for element (type),  if they do call a specific template.

```
<xsl:for-each select="element"> 
    <xsl:if test=". != null">
        <xsl:variable name="showColumn" select="'TRUE'">
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However I then realised that variables are constant values, and cannot be redefined. I am now stuck on how to implement this. Also, doing this with a parameter, it would get overwritten for each call in 'for-each'.  I was initially going to do this, and then afterwards simply test if the value is true, to call one template, if false to call another.

Looking into parameters, my understanding is that I can declare a default value, or this can be overwritten at runtime with the value of a node, but I cannot update this myself.

Again, the goal is to just check if at least one value exists for element.

Comment: How would a "null" value look exactly in XML in general or in your specific case?

Answer (score 0):

The body of your `xsl:for-each select="element"` will only be processed if there are any `element` element nodes. If you need additional checks like `xsl:for-each select="element[normalize-space()]"` you can simply do that in a predicate. For your sample, a predicate `element[type]` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I apologize,  I should have added more detail into the question.  I have updated this to show my xml structure, and what it looks like when there is and isn't data for a given node.